# StreamBuilder child update not rendering after navigation

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I'm using flutter's `StreamBuilder` to decide which "root" page to show a user. Right now there are basically 2 possibilities - `LoginPage` or `HomePage`. My app's main build method looks like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamProvider.value(
      initialData: CurrentUser.initial,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: Consumer<CurrentUser>(
          builder: (context, currentUser, _) => MaterialApp(
              home: currentUser.isInitialValue
                  ? Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    )
                  : currentUser.user != null
                      ? MultiProvider(providers: [
                          Provider<User>.value(value: currentUser.user),
                          // NOTE: Any other user-bound providers here can be added here
                        ], child: HomePage())
                      : LoginPage())));
```

The relevant part of the login page is that it gives you two options:

1. "Are you a new user" - Sign Up
2. "Are you returning" - Sign in

When you click one of those buttons, you go to the form in a certain mode via the navigator:

```
Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                CupertinoPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginPage(
                                    mode: LoginPageMode.signUp,
                                  ),
                                ))
```

After successfully logging in or signing up, the stream gets updated and the `HomePage` renders. I know this because I have a print statement in the build method (`"Building HomePage"`):

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Building HomePage');
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text('HOME'),
    ));
  }
}
```

However, the screen does not actually change. The screen remains on the login page. I think I'm managing the stream fine because if I wasn't the render method would never be hit. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338282/stream-builder-is-not-updating-after-navigation) but it seems they are not managing the stream properly. How can I see the render method hit, yet the screen stay the same? I've been working with Flutter for a while and I've never seen this before.

I think it has something to do with the navigation because if I remove the step where the user chooses "sign in" or "sign up", and I just send them to the sign in page, the issue disappears. It's like the `HomePage` is being built under the page that was navigated to.

Comment: add `key: UniqueKey(),` to `MaterialApp`

Comment: That does help and I have been messing around with the MaterialApp key. However it does cause a strange temporary state where it goes back to the `LoginPage` for a few seconds before going to the `HomePage`. However if I manually build the key `key = user == null ? 'user-null' : '${user.id}'`, it works and this weird intermediate state does not happen. One feels wrong and the other feels hacky. Why isn't flutter rendering when the build method executes? I thought keys were for figuring out whether to call build or not, not for figuring out whether to paint the screen or not ...

Comment: i dont know if its a bug or feature of `MaterialApp` widget - i would need to check both the official docs and the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Explanation

The reason of such behavior is that you use root Navigator that pushes `LoginPage` route on the apps root level. Here is widgets tree reveals widgets relations after push:

```
App
  |
  |-- StreamBuilder
  |      |--LoginPage()
  |
  |-- LoginPage(mode: LoginPageMode.signUp)
```

So when your StreamBuilder changes data the tree becomes this:

```
App
  |
  |-- StreamBuilder
  |      |--HomePage()    // <--- CHANGED
  |
  |-- LoginPage(mode: LoginPageMode.signUp)
```

Thats why you still see `LoginPage` and at the same time `HomePage` rendered too. `HomePage` just lays "under" `LoginPage`.

#### 2. Solution

The solution is to use nested Navigator:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamProvider.value(
      initialData: CurrentUser.initial,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: Consumer<CurrentUser>(
          builder: (context, currentUser, _) => MaterialApp(
              home: currentUser.isInitialValue
                  ? Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    )
                  : currentUser.user != null
                      ? MultiProvider(providers: [
                          Provider<User>.value(value: currentUser.user),
                          // NOTE: Any other user-bound providers here can be added here
                        ], child: HomePage())
                      : Navigator(                //  <--- HERE
                          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                            return CupertinoPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                            );
                          },
                        )));

...
```

In that case when you will call `Navigator.push(context, ...)` inside `LoginPage` your widget tree will look like this:

```
App
  |
  |-- StreamBuilder
         |-- Navigator()
              |-- LoginPage()
              |-- LoginPage(mode: LoginPageMode.signUp)
```

Please try this approach, it should work.