# how to make flutter searchDelagate a separate screen that can be navigated to independently?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a page called searchUsersSCreen which is this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:myApp/models/otherUser.dart';
import 'package:myApp/ui/widgets/user_profile.dart';

import 'database.dart';

class SearchUsersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchUsersScreenState createState() => _SearchUsersScreenState();
}

class _SearchUsersScreenState extends State<SearchUsersScreen> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showSearch(
          context: context,
          delegate: SearchUsers(
            DatabaseService().fetchUsersInSearch(),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }
}
```

and inside the same dart file is have this searchDelegate :

```
//Search delegate
class SearchUsers extends SearchDelegate<OtherUser> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> otherUser;
  final String hashtagSymbol = 'assets/svgs/flaticon/hashtag_symbol.svg';

  SearchUsers(this.otherUser);
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    showUserProfile(String userId) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => UserProfileView(
                    userUid: userId,
                  )));
    }

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: DatabaseService().fetchUsersInSearch(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

          final handlesResults = snapshot.data.documents
              .where((u) => u['username'].contains(query));

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          if (handlesResults.length > 0) {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: ListView(
                children: handlesResults
                    .map<Widget>((u) => GestureDetector(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.1),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom: BorderSide(
                                          width: 0.3, color: Colors.grey[50]))),
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        backgroundImage:
                                            NetworkImage(u['userAvatarUrl']),
                                        radius: 20,
                                      ),
                                title: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(u['username'],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .accentColor),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5,
                                      ),
                                       Text(u['name'],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                              ),
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  height: 43.0,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            showUserProfile(u['id']);
                          },
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No results found',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

i wanted to user the class SearchUsers as a separate screen that i can navigate to independently...but couldn't achieve that as SearchUsers doesn't evaluate to a widget.

so i built SearchUsersScreen statefulWidget and inside it's `initState()` i called this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => showSearch(
          context: context,
          delegate: SearchUsers(
            DatabaseService().fetchUsersInSearch(),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

as to make the search feature starts automatically when the user navigates to SearchUsersScreen.

and i ended up into two problems:

1. SearchUsers is being displayed in full screen ontop of SearchUsersSCreen (which i don't want this behavior), i want it to be displayed inside of it.
   actually its covering the BottomNavigationBar i built for navigation between screens.
2. after SearchUsers is being displayed (and its doing its job well), when i tap the device back button...i leave SearchUsers and get back to SearchUsersScreen....which is indeed a blank screen.

---

so to wrap it up...all i want is to use SearchUsers class as a widget that i can navigate to and navigate from independently...thats it.

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks for your time reading.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this answer can help you to solve your problems with navigation https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059394/10595176. Long story short, use nested navigator.

Comment: thanks for your answer...something new i've learned :) to let you know...i created all of the above approach and ran into problems because i didn't find a solution for my own question here also...which is the main reason i am doing of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114606/how-to-convert-searchdelegate-to-a-statefulwidget

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a separate widget SearchUsers, try to create a dialog and show it when anyone wants to search users. You can also use the navigator and the back button in this case and get arguments passed from the next screen to the previous screen.

Comment: yes might be a good idea....with the showSearch() function i can trigger the searchDelegate class from wherever i want....but the point here...is that i want the searchDelegate to get triggered automatically when i am navigating to a specific page....i tried to make SearchDelegate a stateful or stateless widget but i had no luck....so thats why i created a separate widget and called the search delegate from ints initState() to get triggered once a user navigates to that page

Comment: Why not use Provider for searchDelegate and listen to it in the widget where you want to call the function. Listen to it in the build method and whenever you navigate to it the function will get called.